# Why so many folder in .rvm/gems folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am still trying to understand how rvm works and have few questions. I will really appreciate if someone can help me understanding it better

1 - I did **gem  env** and got this

```
 GEM PATHS:
   /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
   /home/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
```

why 2 different folders for gem ?

2 - in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194 folder, I have multiple directories

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125@ajax_forms  ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp
ruby-1.9.3-p194             ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_composer
ruby-1.9.3-p194@global      ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-prelaunch-signup
```

how come ? I have created over 30 apps so either there should be 30 folders for gems of every app or there should be only one folder.

Thanks

Comment: [What is a rvm gemset?](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/)

Comment: Do you have `.rvmrc` and/or `.ruby-version` files in your project directories? If so can you show some samples of a few of them in the question, since they probably relate.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have created several gemsets with same ruby version.

Read about gemsets here:

https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/

https://rvm.io/gemsets/listing/

Answer (score 2):

RVM manage different ruby versions. Which also gives facility that is gemset. The gemsets is going to be created by us based on our usage. We can created different gemset for different projects, so that the installed gems between the project can not get conflict.

ex: ruby-1.9.3-p125@ajax_forms

It says that

1. ajax_forms - is a gemset, which contains all the gems specific to a
   project.
2. ruby-1.9.3-p125 - indicates ruby version with patch level.

creating different gemsets are not mandatory, but if you do it gives clarity on gems used for a particular project.

When we switch to different ruby version, then if you give command rvm gemset list will list all the gemssets created under this ruby version.

Comment: Thanks Mohan, I don't remember creating any gemset, so when do they get created ? when I am creating any app, can I (and how) specify that create it with this ruby version ?

Comment: Exactly you can specify the ruby version and also you can create a new gemset or use existing gemset, please follow the instruction,
 
1 . rvm list - command list you the all the installed ruby versions
    ex:rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ i686 ]
2 . rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320 - select which ruby version you need for your app.
3 . rvm gemset list - list all the gemsets in current ruby version used, selected by above step.
   ex:=> (default)
   global
   sandbox
4 . rvm gemset create sandbox1 - create a new gemset under the current ruby

Comment: step 5: rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320@sandbox1  - this command sets your current ruby version and gemset usage.
note: "default" gemset is the defaultly available gemset. And also you can create .rvmrc file under app root dir, and put "rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p320@sandbox1" line, this will select the specified ruby and gemset when you entering into app dir.